# Newly added Form Elements doesn't get binded for client side validation in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side, unobtrusive-validation

I have AJAX Form in MVC 3.

In Index view:

```
<div id="ajaxcontactform">
      <% Html.RenderPartial("ContactForm", Model); %>
</div>
```

AJAX form on ContactForm Partial View

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", new AjaxOptions()
{
   UpdateTargetId = "ajaxcontactform",
   OnBegin = "ShowProcessing",
   OnComplete = "HideProessing",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary()%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { Class = "contacttextform" })%>
<%}%>
```

My controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactForm form)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
             // on error
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return PartialView("ContactForm", form);

           // TODO: My data processing code here  

           // return partial view on success
             return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactFormModel());   
         }
   }
```

my client side custom validation JavaScript code:
I just referenced this file in master page. This code runs once when DOM get loaded/created once.

```
    $.validator.addMethod("phonenumber", function (value, element, params) {

    if (!value)
        return true;
    var regex = /^[\s\d\+\(\)]+$/;
    return regex.test(value);
   });
   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("phonenumber");
```

My client side validation works fine when I first load my page. However, once i submit my form successfully and try to submit my form again . My client side validation doesn't work and my form validate it server side.

I want to bind my client side validation again after adding new element or re-render my partial view.

Also, how should I clear my form values once it submitted successfully.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` method in the `AjaxOptions` and reattach the client side validation of the newly added elements using the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method:

```
function OnSuccess(result) {
    $('form').removeData('validator');
    $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. client side validation works after re-rendering the partial view. cheers